# A namespace cannot directly contain members... + Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected errors

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm trying to compile the sample code for Sync Framework 4.0 for Windows Phone, however I've encountered an error in few files. One of those files is:

```
#if SERVER
namespace Microsoft.Synchronization.Services
#elif CLIENT
namespace Microsoft.Synchronization.ClientServices
#endif
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the base interface that all offline cacheable object should derive from.
    /// </summary>
    public interface IOfflineEntity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Represents the sync and OData metadata used for the entity
        /// </summary>
        OfflineEntityMetadata ServiceMetadata { get; set; }
    }
}
```

There are two errors:

- A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods      -- for the first parenthesis
- Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected    -- for the last parenthesis

I've searched through the google for both of those errors and I've found lots of answers for such errors - however none of those can be applied to my case (afaik there are no missing parentheses).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this error because you have neither SERVER nor CLIENT [conditional symbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691095%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) defined. After preprocessing phase eliminates text in [#if](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk)...[#endif](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx43has) directives, compiler sees only this code:

```
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the base interface that all offline cacheable object should derive from.
    /// </summary>
    public interface IOfflineEntity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Represents the sync and OData metadata used for the entity
        /// </summary>
        OfflineEntityMetadata ServiceMetadata { get; set; }
    }
}
```

which is not valid C# code (because "namespace xyz" is missing before opening curly brace).

In Visual Studio go to project properties and on page *Build* set *Conditional compilation symbols* to SERVER or CLIENT (names are case sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because my .TT file had UNIX style line breaks in it, presumably because the line breaks were converted by git. Copying the .tt file into a text editor, saving it in PC format, and then copying back into Visual Studio solved the problem for me.